# How to draw nodes and edges in blog

Tags: graph-drawing

I started writing a blog. I am new at it. 
can someone help me how to draw nodes/edges and also colouring/editing like this:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any software or any website, where i can get help?

Example: like [this post](http://www.shafaetsplanet.com/?p=1831), I want to draw image like that and how to code like that in a box.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several ways of drawing a "professional" looking graph:

1. Use [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/), e.g. with a graph defined through a .dot file.
2. Use [tikz](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package) in LaTeX, e.g. in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/).
3. Draw it manually in e.g. [Google Slides](http://slides.google.com/), and stylize it with e.g. Times New Roman font.

The first two approaches have the advantage that you don't draw anything directly, but rather define the graph textually, which also makes it easy to edit later if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is **Cacoo**, an *Online Diagram and Flowchart Software*. Free trial and easy WYSIWYG interface available on [cacoo.com](https://cacoo.com/). I did with Cacoo two diagrams that I included in my BSc thesis and both were very similar to the one included in your question.

Instead, if using [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/), the package [`forest`](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest) may be appropriate.